# Update Manager cannot update due to dpkg error... (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: updates, package-management, dpkg, xserver

I just downloaded the updates to Ubuntu 12.10; however, when I attempt to install these packages, I get this error [via Update Manager]:

```
installArchives() failed:
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 36442 package 'xserver-xorg-video-intel':
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `dpkg -configure -a`

This command finish a disturbed update.

or

`sudo dpkg --clear-avail` - that will be my last guess

then

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Wait a minute... what was that second command again???

Comment: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 36442 package 'xserver-xorg-video-intel':
 `Depends' field, reference to `libdrm-intel1': version contains ` '
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: I tried, but it gave me an additional error message...sheesh!

Comment: sudo apt-get clean   - this command will clear all the downloaded packages. and then try update.

Comment: Nope...it still didn't work. I'm still getting that same error message...

Comment: 'sudo dpkg --clear-avail'  - that will be my last guess

Comment: Hallelujah! It worked!!! Thank you soooo much, @Herby.Pepper! Thanks to that command...it is finally updating!